# how can I do a back propagation for a simple neural net with sigmoid activation?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I am a beginner in deep learning. I am currently struggled with the back propagation algorithms. I found this piece of code online of the back propagation of a simple neural net with sigmoid activation function.

```
#Step 1 Collect Data
x = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]])
y = np.array([[0], [1], [1], [0]])

#Step 2 build model
num_epochs = 60000

#initialize weights
syn0 = 2np.random.random((3,4)) - 1 
syn1 = 2np.random.random((4,1)) - 1

def nonlin(x,deriv=False):
    if(deriv==True): return x*(1-x)
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    for j in xrange(num_epochs): #feed forward through layers 0,1, and 2
        k0 = x
        k1 = nonlin(np.dot(k0, syn0))
        k2 = nonlin(np.dot(k1, syn1))

        #how much did we miss the target value?
        k2_error = y - k2

        if (j% 10000) == 0:
            print "Error:" + str(np.mean(np.abs(k2_error)))

        #in what direction is the target value?
        k2_delta = k2_error*nonlin(k2, deriv=True)

        #how much did each k1 value contribute to k2 error
        k1_error = k2_delta.dot(syn1.T)
        k1_delta= k1_error * nonlin(k1,deriv=True)
        syn1 += k1.T.dot(k2_delta)
        syn0 += k0.T.dot(k1_delta)
```

I do not get this line of code: `k2_delta = k2_error*nonlin(k2, deriv=True)`. When calculating the local gradient why it uses `k2_error` multiply the derivative of k2. Should we use a different thing instead of `k2_error` because the cost function in this algorithm is absolute value, so should I use a vector of `[-1,1,1,-1]` as the local gradient of the cost function? I assume here it uses analytics gradient.

Comment: The expressions you show, are they in any specific language? Using any specific framework? Then please [*edit your question*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45195760/edit) to include the language and possible framework as tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `k2_error` as it's written. I tested your code (after making a formatting change) and confirmed that it minimizes the absolute error, which is different from `k2_error` (the ostensible but not actual target of gradient descent in your algorithm). `k2_delta = k2_error*nonlin(k2, deriv=True)` because the algorithm is minimizing the absolute error instead of `k2_error`. Here's how that works:

**The relationship between `k2_error` and the input to `k2`**

The derivative of `k2_error` with respect to `k2` is -1. Using the chain rule, the derivative of `k2_error` with respect to the input of `k2` is `(-1)*(nonlin(k2, deriv=True))`.

Thus:

- The derivative of `k2_error` with respect to the input of `k2` is always negative. This is because `(nonlin(k2, deriv=True))` is always positive.
- Regular gradient descent minimization of `k2_error` will therefore always want to push the input of `k2` up (make it more positive) to make `k2_error` more negative.

**Minimize the absolute error**

There are two practical possibilities for `k2_error = y-k2`, and each possibility implies a different strategy for minimizing the absolute error (our real goal). (There's an unlikely third possibility that we can ignore.)

- Case 1: `y`<`k2`, which means `k2_error`<0

  - To make `y` and `k2` closer together (minimize the absolute error), we need to make the error larger/more-positive. We know from the first section that we can do this by pushing the input of `k2` down (`k2_error` increases when the input to `k2` decreases).
- Case 2: `y`>`k2`, which means `k2_error`>0

  - To make `y` and `k2` closer together (minimize the absolute error), we need to make the error smaller/more-negative. We know from the first section that we can do this by pushing the input of `k2` up (`k2_error` decreases when the input to `k2` increases).

In summary, if `k2_error` is negative (Case 1), we minimize the absolute error by pushing the input of `k2` down. If `k2_error` is positive (Case 2), we minimize the absolute error by pushing the input of `k2` up.

**Explanation of `k2_delta`**

We now know that gradient descent minimization of `k2_error` will always want to push the input of `k2` up, but this will only minimize the absolute error when `y` > `k2` (Case 2 from above). In Case 1, pushing the input of `k2` up will *increase* the absolute error--so we modify the gradient at the input of `k2`, which is called `k2_delta`, by flipping its sign whenever we are facing Case 1. Case 1 implies that `k2_error`<0, which means that we can flip the sign of the gradient by multiplying `k2_delta` by `k2_error`! Using this flip means that when we see Case 1, gradient descent wants to push the input of `k2` down instead of up (we force gradient descent to abandon its default behavior).

To summarize, using `k2_delta = k2_error*nonlin(k2, deriv=True)` flips the sign of the usual gradient only when we're facing Case 1, which ensures we are always minimizing the absolute error (as opposed to minimizing `k2_error`).

**Important notes**

Your algorithm modifies the weights by adding the negative gradient. Typically, gradient descent modifies the weights by subtracting the gradient. Adding the negative gradient is the same thing, but it does complicate my answer somewhat. For instance, the gradient at the input of `k2` is actually `k2_delta = k2_error*(-1)*nonlin(k2, deriv=True)`, not `k2_delta = k2_error*nonlin(k2, deriv=True)`.

You may be wondering why we use `k2_error` instead of `sign(k2_error)`, and that's because we want to move the weights by smaller amounts as `k2_error` becomes smaller.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. You are a lifesaver!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code was taken from here: http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

There are good explanations for every step.

Cost function here is the difference between the actual and the expected values:

```
k2_error = y - k2
```

Therefore we multiply it by a derivative of activation function.

Comment: I think the real loss function here is the absolute value of the k2_error and should the derivative of that be [-1,1,1,-1].